# WM_CLOSE message and application freeze

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

Having such supers simple Win app:

```
int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int       nCmdShow) {    
                
    ...

    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);     

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance(hInstance, nCmdShow)) {
        return FALSE;
    }       

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_GL1WIN));

    MSG msg;        

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) {

        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg)) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);

        }       
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}  

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {               

    switch (message) {

        case WM_COMMAND: {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId) {
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;          

        case WM_CLOSE:              
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:                
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

When the `WM_CLOSE` case is disabled (commented out) everything works OK - when i click the `X` button the window closes but when the `WM_CLOSE` case is enabled like in the above code the app seems to freeze - doesn't react when clicking the `X` button and i have to kill it from the `task manager`.

Comment: What do you think your code does when `WM_CLOSE` is received by the message loop? You go directly to the `return 0;` statement. Or, maybe I should ask: What do you *want* your code to do? If you don't handle the message, you should return a non-zero value.

Comment: That's not matter what the code in WM_CLOSE case is. There may be just `OutputDebugString(L"WM_CLOSE ");` instruction. My problem is as I've already written that just only the presents in the code of WM_CLOSE case makes the app freeze.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On WM_CLOSE the window should normally be destroyed with `DestroyWindow`, like:

```
 case WM_CLOSE:   
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
```

In your case you just return without doing anything with that window, so it simple 'freezes'.

Comment: So i have to either call the `DestroyWindow` method in WM_CLOSE or just remove it?

Comment: If you want to destroy the window in response to `WM_CLOSE` message, then you should either call `DestroyWindow` in the handler of that message, or pass the message along to `DefWindowProc` which will call `DestroyWindow` for you. There are many ways to arrange the code to achieve one of these outcomes.

Comment: Yeah, you can ignore WM_CLOSE and nothing happens, or you do something with it, like DestroyWindow

Answer (score 2):

Without `WM_CLOSE` case, the message is passed to `DefWindowProc` that reacts to it by destroying the window. With `WM_CLOSE` case, you handle the message and don't pass it to `DefWindowProc` - then it's your responsibility to do *something* in response to that message.